# Does startWith() operator turns Observable into ReplaySubject(1)?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

If I want subscribers to initially get at least **X**, can I use **startWith( X )** for an existing Observable:

```
streamFromLibrary.startWith( X ).subscribe( myHandler );
//I want myHandler() to not wait until streamFromLibrary produce a value
//but be called instantly with X
```

or it still needs to be carried through intermediate **ReplaySubject( 1 )** like this?

```
let carrier = new Rx.ReplaySubject( 1 );
carrier.next( X );
streamFromLibrary.subscribe( value => carrier.next( value ) );
carrier.subscribe( myHandler );
```

Or if not, is there any other more elegant way to carry values from existing streams into subscription with at least one initial/last value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `ReplaySubject`, however you should know that these two aren't the same:

- The `startWith()` operator just emits a preset value to every observer when they subscribe.
- The `ReplaySubject(1)` class re-emits the one last item that went through it. So the first value it emits to every observer might not be the same depending on what you pushed into this Subject.

Note, that there's also `BehaviorSubject` that takes its initial value as a parameter and then overrides it with every emission so it works very similarly to `ReplaySubject(1)`.

However there's one important distinction. When `BehaviorSubject` receives `complete` notification it never ever emits anything. On the other hand `ReplaySubject` always replays its buffer to every observer even though it has already received the `complete` notification.

Comment: So how can I make **myHandler()** be called with at least some value before **streamFromLibrary** produces any new value in the future?

Comment: Exactly the way you're doing it right now `streamFromLibrary.startWith( X ).subscribe( myHandler );`

Comment: Oops, I wasn't expecting for it to actually work - thought that **X** will just extinguish since there are no subscribers at the moment. Thanks!